# Laravel Manually generating reset password token : Getting error "This password reset token is invalid"

Tags: laravel, passwords, token, reset, forgot-password

I am trying to generate reset password token manually in laravel.

```
$string = hash_hmac('sha256', Str::random(40), "my hash string");
```

then I got "**0afa340dc692ffa51c1ba12b1db8819a8e4eaebb44a991bb288c3af877d36ee6**"

I hashed this string with

```
$hash = Hash::make($string);
```

then I got

**$2y$10$onDUmasKFCF9r1.VwOq3ze7Kx225UZK/HkwoUmH4h5dRo/8iCV2Be**

I saved the hashed token in "**password_resets**" table corresponding to an email id.
I replaced the generated string in the reset password url and tried to reset the password of specified email, but I am always getting "**This password reset token is invalid**" .

Is there any mistake from my manual generation. Please help.

Comment: see here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18570

Answer (score 2):

this function in your model will generate password rest link:

```
public function getNewPassResetUrl(){
    $token=str_random(60);
    \DB::table('admin_password_resets')->where('email',$this->email)->delete();
    \DB::table('admin_password_resets')->insert([
        'email' => $this->email,
        'token' => \Hash::make($token), //change 60 to any length you want
        'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()
    ]);
    return url('reset',$token);
}
```

Comment: can you please clear your answer more which model you are talking about I have the same problem here

Comment: How do you unhash the token right after the user clicks on the reset link??? ('cuz I get the `invalid token error`)

Answer (score 1):

To generate a token you can do as the snippet below, this has the added benefit using Laravel's implementation, so if at some point it changes, you do not need to change anything.

```php
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::broker('users')->createToken($user);
```